# How to make a submenu do a function onclick in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to make a simple menu with submenus on the top of any program's window which does any function you'd like on clicking the submenu, Say for example you click on Menu, it opens "sub-menu", you click on sub-menu and it does this function in which the window's title changes using SetWindowTextA.

```
SetWindowTextA(ROBLOX, "a"); // we set the text of the window title to whatever you want, in this case "a"


        HMENU SubSX = CreatePopupMenu(); //Create a submenu which appears on hovering to "menu" called "Sub-Menu"

        AppendMenu(SX, MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)SubSX, "Sub-Menu");


        HMENU SX = CreateMenu(); //Create the main menu ontop of a window called "Menu"

        AppendMenu(SX, MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)SubSX, "Menu");


        SetMenu(ROBLOX, SX);
```

**As you have seen in the code above, I created a menu with a submenu called Sub-Menu**
**ROBLOX is the handle of the window, not our concern now**

The menu and submenus in action:
[image]

So, What i basically want to do is that when you click on the submenu, say for example "Sub-Menu" in the picture above, it does a specific function (example: change the window title using SetWindowText)

I know it needs some sort of windows hooking but I don't know how, Any help will be needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a menu item is clicked, it issues a `WM_COMMAND` message to the `HWND` that owns the menu. Which in this case is the `HWND` that you pass to `SetMenu()`. If that `HWND` is for a window in another process, then you will have to either 1) inject code into that process to subclass the window directly; or 2) use a message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`, where the hook procedure is implemented inside a DLL that will get injected into the target process for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can create an identifier to determine the menu item to control, like `#define IDM_SUBSX 1001`.

Then use the [`AppendMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenua) to specify the menu item by the identifier: `AppendMenu(SubSX, MF_STRING, IDM_SUBSX, "Sub-Menu");`.

Finally, through the [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) message to determine the identifier of the menu item, we can do different operations for different menu items according to the identifier.

Here is the Sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
#define IDM_SUBSX 1001
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetWindowTextA(hwnd, "a"); // we set the text of the window title to whatever you want, in this case "a"

        HMENU SX = CreateMenu();
        HMENU SubSX = CreatePopupMenu(); //Create a submenu which appears on hovering to "menu" called "Sub-Menu"
        AppendMenu(SubSX, MF_STRING, IDM_SUBSX, "Sub-Menu");
        AppendMenu(SX, MF_POPUP | MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR)SubSX, "Menu");

        SetMenu(hwnd, SX);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawTextW(hdc, (L"Hello,Windows"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDM_SUBSX:
            SetWindowTextA(hwnd, "TITLE CHANGED"); 
            return 0;
        default:
            break;
        };

        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```